# For Loop solo imprime el primer registro multiples veces

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, loops

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Estoy recorriendo una lista que contiene multiples registros, pero al momento de imprimir esta informacion solo me muestra el primer row multiples veces, digamos que un usuario especifico tiene 49 rows en BD y me imprime el primer valor pero 49 vecesm me explico ?

Algo debe estar mal en el codigo :

> DaoImp

```
public List<Permisos> obtenerListaPermisos(String username){

List<Permisos> resultado = new ArrayList<Permisos>();
String queryString ="";
queryString ="SELECT * FROM EBSQP.PERMISOS  where USER_NAME='"+username+"' ";
Query consulta =   entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString,Permisos.class);
resultado = consulta.getResultList();
return resultado;
}
```

> Controller

```
   List<Permisos> permisos = new ArrayList<Permisos>();
        permisos = (List<Permisos>) permisosDao.obtenerListaPermisos(usuarioPaso);

        for(int i =0; i<permisos.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(permisos.get(i).getId_acceso());
          }
```

> Mapeo Tabla

```
package com.c5.application.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="PERMISOS")
public class Permisos implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(nullable=false)
private String user_name;

@Id
@Column(name="ID_ACCESO")
private BigDecimal idAcceso;


public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}

public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}

public BigDecimal getIdAcceso() {
    return this.idAcceso;
}

public void setIdAcceso(BigDecimal idAcceso) {
    this.idAcceso = idAcceso;
}

 }
```

Y como les mencione solo me muestra el primer registro 49 veces.

Quedo en espera de comentarios.

Estoy usando Spring MVC, Hibernate,Oracle,Eclipse

Comment: Intente hacer un DEBUG y ver si la lista permisos que devuelve su método  `obtenerListaPermisos` contiene los 49 registros antes de ingresar al for.

Comment: Hola @Dev.Joel en efecto esta devolviendo el metodo obtenerListaPermisos pero pintandome solo el primer valor.

Comment: Verifico entonces que la variable permisos de su controller tiene los 49 registros diferentes (getId_Acceso) que es lo que está imprimiendo.?

Comment: Fuera de los múltiples problemas que tienes con el código, supongo dos cosas: 1) Tu información en la base de datos contiene duplicados. 2) El mapeo de tus entidades hacia los objetos de base de datos está ocasionando este problema.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza La informacion en la base de datos no contiene duplicados.  en referencia al Mapeo no creo que este mal,, de todos modos deja actualizo el codigo de arriba para que puedas ver el mapeo. Saludos

Comment: En un ide sql ejecuta el query que arma Hibernate. ¿Te devuelve los mismos 49 registros repetidos?

Comment: @Voiser Ya lo he resuelto, el problema era el tipo de dato que estaba usando para el campo que necesitaba. Saludos.